# Unable to Merge Multiple .DXF Files and Output .DXF Using Merge Vector Layers

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, merge, dxf

I'm using QGIS 3.8.3 with GRASS 7.6.1 to merge multiple .dxf files into a single .dxf file.

When I attempt to use the Merge Vector Layers via Vector>Data Management tools>Merge Vector Layers, I get the following error "Creation of field path failed (OGR error: DXF layer does not support arbitrary field creation, field 'path' not created.)" when I attempt 
1. Add number of .dxf files as the input layer.
2. Output it as a .dxf file.

When I output it as a temporary file, it doesn't show anything even though it looks like the attribute table is populated with features.

I don't have any issues viewing each individual .dxf file when I import them into qGIS.

I also don't have any issues when I convert them via GRASS v.patch but I was hoping that Merge Vector Layers would be faster as it looks like v.patch imports each file via v.in.ogr and processes it as a GRASS vector layer, merges each of the GRASS vector layers via v.patch and before using v.out.ogr to output it.

I've been told that doing the merging these .dxf files via Global Mapper into a single .dxf file takes 15 to 20 mins but using QGIS's GRASS v.patch takes a bit over an hour so I was wondering whether there's a better way to do it in QGIS/GRASS.

Comment: Iirc qgis can't really edit dxf layers hence why it couldn't add the fields customarily added with merge layers (path and filename). Try combining them with merge layers to another spatial format, then either export back the result back out to dxf using save as, or using project > export project to dxf (which ports over symbology as well)?